# Codeinsertion plugin for CKEditor

Tags: jquery, plugins, ckeditor, wysiwyg

CKEditor is nice WYSIWYG editor, im really like it but i have a problem to find codeinsertion plugin. Basicaly i want nothing special, just something like its labeled "Code Sample" and that wraps content in <code></code> tags. Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend some time and make this plugin on my own, here is my sollution :)

[Insertcode.zip](http://hackergeist.com/plugins/insertcode.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Styles" dropdown in the default configuration and select "Computer code".

Comment: thanx for answer, but this is not what i want, i dont want to have style dropdown, i want only one simple button like Bold or Italic

Comment: That shows that you can create a button if you want, just using the built-in features of the CKEditor Style system. If you want a button, then first create a plugin with your button and on the execute method create a style object with the "code" tag and apply it to the document.

Comment: my point was avoid to make this on my own and save some time for me, but no matter, its done, i will put here my plugin :) btw basicstyles plugin was better as example like styles plugin

Comment: I suggested some time ago to use the basicstyles as the starting point for a similar request, and he didn't like because he couldn't understand how it works, so now I might skip to give this kind of suggestions when the user doesn't have any code so far.